# a 3d numerical integration problem

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I need to do the following integration

$$I = \iiint_{[-\pi,\pi]^3} \frac{d x dy dz }{2 \cos x + 2 \cos y + 2 \cos z - 6 }. $$

The singularity at the origin is $1/r^2$, so it is integrable.

But numerically, how to perform this integral? Would the singularity make the convergence slow?

Comment: @coffeemath yes

Comment: Your integral appear in computation of [Polya's Random Walk constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyasRandomWalkConstants.html) for 3d. Based on above link, it evaluates to $-\frac{1}{4\sqrt{6}}\Gamma(\frac1{24})\Gamma(\frac{5}{24})\Gamma(\frac7{24})\Gamma(\frac{11}{24})$